# Use of Curly Brackets (Braces) Around a variable C++

Tags: c++, initialization, declaration, curly-braces

I'm learning 2D arrays in my programming class.  My teacher used something without explaining it and I was curious why we used it.  Since it has to do with a symbol I'm not sure how to google or search for it, as these symbols are used in the search itself.  Anyways the code was this:

`int small[26]= {0}, large[26]={0}, i;`

Why are the curly braces needed around the 0's?

The program this code is a part of examines a file and looks for each letter of the alphabet and counts them individually.

Comment: Instead of asking why the curly braces are needed, you should be asking why the `0` is needed. It isn't. What you have here is an initializer, and it uses the specified values, if any, to initialize the corresponding items of the array, and initializes the rest of the array to zero (or the default value of the type).

Comment: Ok, still, what purpose do they serve?

Comment: These are not 2D arrays, just plain C style arrays.

Comment: Also `0` is a integer literal; not a variable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It could be written even simpler

```
int small[26]= {}, large[26]={}, i;
```

The curly brackets means an initializer list in this case of arrays.

Let assume for example that you want to define an array with elements 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

You could write

```
int a[5];

a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;
a[3] = 4;
a[4] = 5;
```

However C++ allows to assign elements of an array when it is defined. The equivalent record will look

```
int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

If there are initializers less than the size of the array then remaining elements will be initialized by zeroes. For example

```
int a[5] = { 1, 2 };
```

In this case a[0] will be equal tp 1 a[1] will be equal to 2 and all other elements will be equal to 0.

You may omit the size of an array. For example

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

In this case the compiler will allocate as many elements of the array as there are initializers in the initializer list.

Record (valid only in C++. In C it is not allowed)

```
int a[5] = {};
```

is equivalent to

```
int a[5] = { 0 };
```

that is all elements of the array will be initialized by 0. In the last record the first element is initialized explicitly by zero and all other elements are also initialized by zero because their initializers in the initializer list were not specified.

The same way you can initialize also scalar objects. For example

int x = { 10 };

The only difference that for scalar objects you can specify only one initializer. You even may write without the assignment operator

```
int x { 10 };
```

You also can write

```
int x {};
```

In this case x will be initialized by 0.

Comment: When I first saw this `int x { 10 };` kind of expression in a C++ tutorial I was very confused. C++, why do you allow this at all?!

Answer (score 2):

```
int Array[26]= {0};
```

Initializes all elements in that array to 0.

As BryanChen mentions below:

```
Note: int Array[26]= {1}; will initialize first element to 1 and others to 0.
```

Comment: Note: `int Array[26]= {1};` will initialize first element to 1 and others to 0.

Comment: How would one initialize all values to 1?

Comment: Either int Array[26] = { 1,1,1,1,1 ...} with 26 1s, or create a loop that counts the exact number you need in.

Answer (score 1):

By default, regular arrays of local scope (for example, those declared within a function) are left uninitialized. This means that none of its elements are set to any particular value; their contents are undetermined at the point the array is declared.

But the elements in an array can be explicitly initialized to specific values when it is declared, by enclosing those initial values in braces {}.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
int array [constant] = {};
```

Default initializes all values. The default initializer for `int` is 0.

```
int small[26]= {0};
```

Sets the first number to 0 and default initializes the rest.

In general:

```
int array [constant] = {value initialize all indices listed here, 
                        the rest are default initialized};
```